# Is it possible to scan a beacon with location service disable using objective C?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, location-services, beacon

I am able to scan beacon successfully if Bluetooth and location services are turned on. But I want to know is there any way to scan beacon when Bluetooth is on mode and location service is in off mode.

I have used this code but this delegate method is not called when location service is off

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

Can anyone please elaborate how we can scan beacon without location services?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah you can do I guess.

Answer (score 2):

With Bluetooth on but location off, **you can detect Bluetooth LE beacon devices only with `CoreBluetooth` APIs and not with `CoreLocation` APIs.**

This effectively prevents you from detecting iBeacon transmissions, because iOS blocks their detection via `CoreBluetooth`. See my blog post here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

You can, however use `CoreBluetooth` to detect other beacon formats such as AltBeacon and Eddystone.  I have open source code showing how to do that with [iOS beacon tools](https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools).

Using the tools above, here is an example of scanning for AltBeacon, Eddystone-UID, Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-EID, and logging the identifiers detected:

```
self.beaconParsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
RNLBeaconParser *altBeaconParser = [[RNLBeaconParser alloc] init];
[altBeaconParser setBeaconLayout:@"m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25" error: Nil ];
RNLBeaconParser *uidBeaconParser = [[RNLBeaconParser alloc] init];
[uidBeaconParser setBeaconLayout:@"s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19" error: Nil];
RNLBeaconParser *urlBeaconParser = [[RNLBeaconParser alloc] init];
[urlBeaconParser setBeaconLayout:@"s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v" error: Nil];
RNLBeaconParser *eidBeaconParser = [[RNLBeaconParser alloc] init];
[eidBeaconParser setBeaconLayout:@"s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=30,p:3-3:-41,i:4-11" error: Nil];
self.beaconParsers = @[ altBeaconParser, uidBeaconParser, urlBeaconParser, eidBeaconParser ];
self.cbManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                                  options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:
                                                               @"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];

...

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
  if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn && self.scanning) {
    CBUUID *eddystone16BitUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FEAA"];
    NSLog(@"eddy uuid is %@", [eddystone16BitUUID UUIDString]);
    [self.cbManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[eddystone16BitUUID] options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @(YES)}];
    // this scans for BLE peripherals including beacons
    [self.cbManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @(YES)}];

  }
  else {
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
      NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth state UNKNOWN");
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateResetting)  {
      NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth state RESETTING");
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported)  {
      NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth state UNSUPPORTED");
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized)  {
      NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth state UNAUTHORIZED");
    }
    else if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff)  {
      NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth state POWERED OFF");
    }
  }
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
  NSDictionary *serviceData = advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataServiceData"];

  RNLBeacon *beacon = Nil;
  NSData *adData = advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];

  for (RNLBeaconParser *beaconParser in self.beaconParsers) {
    if (adData) {
      beacon = [beaconParser fromScanData: adData withRssi: RSSI forDevice: peripheral serviceUuid: Nil];
      beacon.bluetoothIdentifier = [peripheral.identifier UUIDString];
    }
    else if (serviceData != Nil) {
      for (NSObject *key in serviceData.allKeys) {
        NSString *uuidString = [(CBUUID *) key UUIDString];
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: uuidString];
        unsigned long long uuidLongLong;

        [scanner scanHexLongLong: &uuidLongLong];
        NSNumber *uuidNumber = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:uuidLongLong];

        NSData *adServiceData = [serviceData objectForKey:key];
        if (adServiceData) {
          beacon = [beaconParser fromScanData: adServiceData withRssi: RSSI forDevice: peripheral serviceUuid: uuidNumber];
        }
      }
    }
    if (beacon != Nil) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (beacon != Nil) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", beacon.id1, beacon.id2, beacon.id3];
    NSLog(@"Detected beacon: %@", key);
}
```

Comment: But  Crome widget is able to scan for IBeacon even location service is off. Can you please share your knowledge behind this?

Comment: The Chrome widget scans for Eddystone-URL transmissions, not iBeacon transmissions.  This is why that is possible without CoreLocation.  See more here :http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/22/how-to-push-messages-without-an-app.html

Comment: See my answer edits with a link to tests demonstrating you cannot detect iBeacon with CoreBluetooth and code to detect other beacon formats with CoreBluetooth.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how we can use CoreBluetooth frame work to scan Eddystone beacons?

Comment: so can we just publish our app in appstore using this approach? @davidgyoung

Comment: Yes you can!  Here's an example app I worked on that detects Eddystone beacons using this approach:  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/horti-beacon/id983288051?mt=8

Comment: I would like to detect all the beacons on iOS (Eddystone and iBeacon). I would like to scan the beacons during the background mode also. I planned to scan the Eddystone through the CoreBluetooth and iBeacon through  the CoreLocation. The issue here is, CLBeaconRegion is restricted to 20. So what will be the better way to achieve all the nearby beacons? Seems like I can't detect the iBeacon's via CoreBluetooth using scanForPeripheralsWithServices:service. if I can, what will be the service UUID of the iBeacon? I'm using FEAA for Eddystone? any suggestion on this is highly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, you simply cannot scan for all iBeacon UUIDs with public APIs on iOS.  Apple intentionally disallows it.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can use the system iBeacon support with location services turned off. iBeacon support is provided by the Core Location framework.

You might be able to write low-level BLE code that looks for the messages from iBeacons, but I've seen posts from people who have been unable to figure out how to do that. Plus you would lose the benefits Core Location offers, like getting notified about beacons even if your app isn't running when the beacon is detected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how Google Crome is able to scan for beacon even location service is off? As we can see nearest beacon in widget for Crome. Can you please share some idea behind this?

Comment: I suspect they have their own BLE library that detects iBeacons.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use iBeacon without Location service. Check what apple Documentation is said about it :

> iBeacon works with Location Services in iOS. With iBeacon, your iOS
>   device can alert apps when you approach or leave a location. In
>   addition to monitoring your location, an app knows when you’re close
>   to an iBeacon, like a checkout counter in a retail store. Instead of
>   using latitude and longitude to determine your location, iBeacon uses
>   a Bluetooth low energy signal that is detected by your iOS device.

For more details you can read [Apple support for iBracon](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202880)

Hope this will help :)